# createstream of tweets in Spark

Tags: scala, stream, apache-spark, twitter4j, tweets

I'm trying to create a stream of tweets in Spark using Scala and Twitter4j.
This is a snippet of my code:

```
object auth{
      val config = new twitter4j.conf.ConfigurationBuilder()
        .setOAuthConsumerKey("")
        .setOAuthConsumerSecret("")
        .setOAuthAccessToken("")
        .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("")
        .build
            }
    val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[2]").setAppName("Tutorial")  
    val ssc = new StreamingContext(conf, Seconds(1))

    val twitter_auth = new TwitterFactory(auth.config)
    val a = new twitter4j.auth.OAuthAuthorization(auth.config)
    val atwitter =  twitter_auth.getInstance(a).getAuthorization()
```

and when I try to call createstream:

```
val tweets = TwitterUtils.createStream(ssc, atwitter, filters, DISK_ONLY_2)
```

I get this error:

```
[error] /home/shaza90/Desktop/streaming/scala/Tutorial.scala:30: overloaded method value createStream with alternatives:
[error]   (jssc: org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaStreamingContext,twitterAuth: twitter4j.auth.Authorization,filters: Array[String],storageLevel: org.apache.spark.storage.StorageLevel)org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaReceiverInputDStream[twitter4j.Status] <and>
[error]   (ssc: org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext,twitterAuth: Option[twitter4j.auth.Authorization],filters: Seq[String],storageLevel: org.apache.spark.storage.StorageLevel)org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ReceiverInputDStream[twitter4j.Status]
[error]  cannot be applied to (org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext, twitter4j.auth.Authorization, Seq[String], org.apache.spark.storage.StorageLevel)
[error]     val tweets = TwitterUtils.createStream(ssc, atwitter, filters, DISK_ONLY_2)
[error]                               ^
[error] one error found
[error] (compile:compile) Compilation failed
```

I don't know why it isn't matching the types and seeing my call as an overload, can you assist please? And when I try to replace atwitter (the authorization object) with None it compiles successfully !!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think `atwitter` must be Option[T] to disambiguate the call. 
You  can use:

```
val atwitter : Option[twitter4j.auth.Authorization] =  Some(twitter_auth.getInstance(a).getAuthorization())
```

instead of

```
val tweets = TwitterUtils.createStream(ssc, atwitter, filters, DISK_ONLY_2)
```

You can use: `Some(atwitter)` in the call too... as said.

Here you have the test class for this api: https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/external/twitter/src/test/scala/org/apache/spark/streaming/twitter/TwitterStreamSuite.scala

Comment: it did worked ! Can you please explain that does "some" mean?

Comment: Hi Lisa, I'm glad it worked :) 
In Scala you can use the Option class when returning a value from a function that can be null. 
The value of an Option[type] variable is either Some(value of the correct type) or None

Option[A] is a container for an optional value of type A. If the value of type A is present, the Option[A] is an instance of Some[A], containing the present value of type A. If the value is absent, the Option[A] is the object None.

Comment: As you can see in the example I've post in my answer: 

`val test6: ReceiverInputDStream[Status] = TwitterUtils.createStream(
ssc, Some(authorization), filters, StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER_2)`

You must use `Some(authorization)` to follow the signature include in the error: Option[twitter4j.auth.Authorization]

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the error log, the function signature is following,

```
createStream(
             ssc: org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext,
             twitterAuth: Option[twitter4j.auth.Authorization],
             filters: Seq[String],
             storageLevel: org.apache.spark.storage.StorageLevel
            ): org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ReceiverInputDStream[twitter4j.Status]
```

You are trying to use it like this,

```
val tweets = TwitterUtils.createStream(ssc, atwitter, filters, DISK_ONLY_2)
```

Which means you are calling it with following signature,

```
createStream(
             org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext,
             twitter4j.auth.Authorization,
             Seq[String],
             org.apache.spark.storage.StorageLevel
)
```

Noticed the difference ? it expects `Option[ twitter4j.auth.Authorization ]` and you are providing it `twitter4j.auth.Authorization`. So you need to wrap your `twitter4j.auth.Authorization` with `Option monad` by using  `Some`.

```
val tweets = TwitterUtils.createStream( ssc, Some( atwitter ), filters, DISK_ONLY_2 )
```

For reading more about option type, you can refer to `Nepphtyte's guide to Scala by Daniel Westheide` -> http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2012/12/19/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-5-the-option-type.html which can be said to be one of the best Scala resources for someone with basics of Scala.